We should have a new "subjective/argumentative" post notice
While there are some questions on Bitcoin.SE that have objective answers, a lot of our questions are more subjective than that. In the early days of this SE they were met with close votes, yet, I do believe that there is a lot of constructive and informative expertise between pure fact and pure opinion. 
However, these questions often attract a host of abysmal answers, e.g. statements of differing opinion, one-line answers without explanation and link-only answers.
I would like to propose the creation of a post-notice that could be applied to such questions by moderators with the following content:

This question does not have only one correct answer, it is subjective/argumentative: Constructive and informative answers focus on explaining "Why?" and "How?", and back up any opinions with arguments, facts, or references.
  Give long answers rather than short ones: Opinion by itself is noise and will be deleted.


What do you think: Is this a useful endeavor? Is there a better way of conveying the message than through a post notice? Do you have any ideas how to improve the proposed text of the post notice?

Examples where I think this post notice might be appropriate:

How can Bitcoin solve societal problems caused by capitalism?
Can the price of Bitcoin ever be stable to the USD?
Will we ever need smaller amounts of Bitcoin than a Satoshi?


Could you give examples of where this notice would be appropriate? For example, which of the following questions, if any, should get the tag? 1 2 3

@NickODell If any, then just on the first about quantum computers, the second doesn't have only one objective answer, but you can test the answers whether they work or not in short order. The third I don't find very speculative.
